# Show all possible values of a dimension by another dimension with crossfilter.js and dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Let's consider this dataSet :

```
var dataSet = [{Day :"Monday", Elapsed_Time:120, person:"x"},
               {Day :"Monday", Elapsed_Time:140, person:"y"},
               {Day :"Tueday", Elapsed_Time:160, person:"x"},
               {Day :"Tueday", Elapsed_Time:168, person:"y"},
               {Day :"Wednesday", Elapsed_Time:140, person:"x"},
               {Day :"Wednesday", Elapsed_Time:160, person:"y"},
               {Day :"Thurday", Elapsed_Time:50, person:"x"}, 
               {Day :"Thurday", Elapsed_Time:60, person:"y"},
               {Day :"Friday", Elapsed_Time:80, person:"x"}, 
               {Day :"Friday", Elapsed_Time:170, person:"y"}];
```

With Crossfilter and dc.js I want to create a barChart, to show Elapsed_TimeS by Days, ie : in the x-axis, From Monday to Friday and in each day show the two values without sum ( I don't want the reduceSum )

Thank you in advance;

Comment: What value would you like to display for, say, Monday?

Comment: I didn't get your question, For Monday I want to display the two values of elapsed_time, and doing the same for other days ...

Comment: So you want to show 2 bars for Monday? I'd say either change your group key so that you have the same number of groups as you want bars, or create a fake group (see the dc.js FAQ) based on dimension.top.

Comment: Yes This is what I want sir, but I don't know how to proceed ...

Comment: var dim = crossfilter.dimension(function(d) { return d.Day + d.person; }); var grp = dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.Elapsed_Time; }) should do what you want, more or less.